# Generate documentation for private functions using pydoc

Tags: python, python-3.x, documentation, pdoc

I'm using pdoc to generate html documentation based on python files. Unfortunately private methods like `_example_method` aren't included in documentation. I've tried to use `--all-modules` in pdoc command or set env variable `export PODOC_ALL_SUBMODULES=true`. No one of this solutions didn't work so I'm wondering is there any other option to get result I want to.

Answer (score 2):

pdoc does not provide a builtin switch to document all private methods, because private methods should not be part of your public API and thus should not appear in documentation. If you think that's wrong, you can override pdoc's behavior with a [custom module template](https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#edit-pdocs-html-template).

https://pdoc.dev/docs/pdoc.html#control-what-is-documented is the canonical document detailing how to control visibility.